# Apache POI Footer issue in MS word

Tags: apache-poi, docx

I am using poi to generate docx file.file is getting opened in open office correctly.but in ms word i am getting error "A text/xml declaration may occur only at very beginning of the input in /word/footer1.xml". When i extract my generated docx file i found my /word/footer1.xml with the following code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <w:ftr xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
    <w:p>
     <w:r>
      <w:rPr>
        <w:color w:val="D3D3D3"/>
      </w:rPr>
      <w:t>
        Section 1Page1
      </w:t>
     </w:r>
    </w:p>
  </w:ftr>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<w:ftr xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
<w:p>
  <w:r>
   <w:rPr>
     <w:color w:val="D3D3D3"/>
   </w:rPr>
   <w:t>
     Section   1Page1
   </w:t>
  </w:r>
 </w:p>
</w:ftr>
```

What i got is that xml code is generated twice that's why Ms word is giving that error.What i am not getting what causing it to be generated twice or how can i handle this.My Poi code for footer is as follows

```
CTP ctp = CTP.Factory.newInstance();
        CTR ctr = ctp.addNewR();
        CTRPr rpr = ctr.addNewRPr();
        rpr.setColor( CTColor.Factory.newInstance() );
        style = new WordStyle();
        style.setColor( "D3D3D3" );
        ctr.getRPr().getColor().setVal( style.getColor() );
        CTText text = ctr.addNewT();
        text.setStringValue( parentLevelTitle+" Page 1" );

        XWPFParagraph codePara = new XWPFParagraph( ctp, document );

        XWPFParagraph[] newparagraphs = new XWPFParagraph[1];
        newparagraphs[0] = codePara;

        CTSectPr sectPr = document.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
        CTPageMar ctPageMar = sectPr.addNewPgMar();
        ctPageMar.setLeft( BigInteger.valueOf( 720L ) );
        ctPageMar.setTop( BigInteger.valueOf( 1440L ) );
        ctPageMar.setRight( BigInteger.valueOf( 720L ) );
        ctPageMar.setBottom( BigInteger.valueOf( 1440L ) );
        XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy headerFooterPolicy = new  XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy( document, sectPr );
        headerFooterPolicy.createFooter( STHdrFtr.DEFAULT, newparagraphs );
```

if i removed createFooter statement from code It gets opened successfully in ms-word.
Can anybody suggest how to resolve this ?

Comment: Are you sure you don't already have a footer defined?

Comment: Yes i am.give me your id i'll send you export code.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this is was a bug when creating a header/footer completely from scratch.  I was having this same problem, up to and including POI 3.9.  It is now working correctly with with 3.10FINAL, my code is nearly identical to yours so I'm assuming you will be all set.